# Which action hooks are triggered when new users are created/registered?

Tags: wordpress

I often need to "do things" when new users are created in my Wordpress site. The only action hook that I *know* I can count on is `user_register`.

The problem is that I think it is triggered relatively early in the process of user creation, so often there is user information that is not available or other plugins make changes ***after*** my functions are called.

I've researched but had no luck, what resources explain the way WordPress creates users and which hooks fire when?

Comment: Looks like user_register is your best bet. See http://www.rarescosma.com/2011/04/wordpress-hooks-user_register/ as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9139614/wordpress-add-new-user-hooks. This may also be of help http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/version/3.4

Answer (score 8):

In this case, the best documentation is the [code itself](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/04/learn-to-read-the-source-luke.html).

The hook **`user_register`** is fired in [`/wp-includes/user.php#L1418`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/user.php#L1418) and no other useful action seem to be available there.

We got [**`user_profile_update_errors`**](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-admin/includes/user.php#L153) in `/wp-admin/includes/user.php`, but not sure of its usability here.

The function **[`wp_new_user_notification()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.5.1/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L1184)** called in the previous file is pluggable, meaning that [you can override it](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pluggable_Functions) and do your own stuff there. Maybe it's a good option.

Comment: I'm interested in what you said about overriding `wp_new_user_notification()`. I've used hooks and filters a lot, but I've never overridden core functions. I'll do some research into that. Even though this questions is old, I've run up against the limitations of the `user_register` hook again recently. Specifically, the fact that the automatically created password is already MD5 encrypted when this action fires (the plain text version is stored in a variable earlier in the code but not passed to `user_register`).

Comment: the password is in `$_POST['user_pass']` during the `user_register` action callback.

Comment: the password is in `$_POST['signup_password']`, `user_pass` actually does not exist.

Answer (score 6):

The `user_register` action is actually one of the last registration-related hooks that are triggered. This action is triggered after the record has been saved to the database. There are many different actions and filters that are triggered during the registration process, most of which are called before `user_register`.

`user_register` is fired any time a user is created via the `wp_insert_user()` function. This includes the default WordPress user registration form, the "Add new user" page in the admin dashboard and even custom registration forms that use this function. If you need to target only new users created via the WordPress registration form, you can alternatively use the `register_new_user` action. Similarly, if you want to target only user creation via the admin dashboard (Add new user page), you can use the `edit_user_created_user` action.

There are also other hooks that you can use to implement custom validations rules, for example the `registration_errors` filter. All this is explained with more details in the [A visual guide to WordPress user registration hooks](https://usersinsights.com/wordpress-user-registration-hooks-visualized/) article that goes through all the main registration hooks, including some graphics visualizing the sequence in which they are triggered.